# How to auto deploy code on multiple droplets/servers having LAMP stack in DigitalOcean via SSH?

Tags: web-deployment, digital-ocean, ubuntu-server

Im using LAMP stack droplets. Im looking for automated deployment tool or method to push my code on multiple servers at once. Im using Load balancer for 2 droplets. When i push some code to droplet1, it should also be auto deployed to server2. I tried using Git hooks 2014 answer from DO Community, but was not successful. Or how to use RSYNC or any method? Actively looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ansible technology! It allow you to deploy your code (and more, you can be impressed) to an infinite number of servers.

There is a documentation for a Continuous Deployment system: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/guide_rolling_upgrade.html